# Saving tmp file as video in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm receiving a tmp path from an api and want to convert it into its original file.

Here's the request im receiving (image)

```
{file: "C:\xampp\tmp\php84E5.tmp", file_name: "1596172496.3.jpg"}
```

For images, we can use Image intervention.

```
\Image::make($request->file)->save(public_path('media/content/').$request->file_name);
```

this will make an image and store in the folder. How can i achieve the same result but for videos?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: its a tmp file, i dont want to store it, i want to convert it to video @apokryfos

Comment: I don't understand, isn't it already a video file (albeit with a tmp extension)?

Answer (score 0):

hi this is how I upload video in controller hopefully that can help you

public function store(Request $request)
{
$request->validate([
'video' => 'required|mimetypes:video/avi,video/mpeg,video/quicktime,video/mp4|max:20000',
]);

```
$image_path = request()->video->store('uploads/video','public');
$video = Video::create([]);
$video->image()->create(['name' => $image_path ]);
return back();
}
```

first run a validation on the request name video, then use the store function , store file inside storage , then create record (path) on db.
thanks